# StackApps is not being reported by StackAuth

Tags: bug, status-completed

The stackauth.com sites query is not returning stackapps.com at all:

- http://stackauth.com/0.8/sites?type=jsontext

  ```
  {
    "api_sites": [
      {
        "name": "Stack Overflow",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.stackoverflow.com",
        "site_url": "http://stackoverflow.com",
        "description": "Q&A for programmers",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/so/apple-touch-icon.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Server Fault",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/sf/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.serverfault.com",
        "site_url": "http://serverfault.com",
        "description": "Q&A for system administrators and IT professionals",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/sf/apple-touch-icon.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Super User",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/su/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.superuser.com",
        "site_url": "http://superuser.com",
        "description": "Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/su/apple-touch-icon.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Stack Overflow Meta",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/mso/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com",
        "site_url": "http://meta.stackoverflow.com",
        "description": "Q&A about Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/mso/apple-touch-icon.png"
      }
    ]
  }
  ```

Comment: + confirmed. foo as filler.

Comment: @code: You really are new to these parts, aren't you :) You don't need filler.

Comment: See? _` ` ` ` ` `_

Comment: I know the reason it got removed - it's because SA image is really in an image sprite, not a standalone one... Not really, the image IS a sprite though...

Comment: @Igor: What? I'm talking about the whole site not appearing in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

A configuration error lingering from our recent Area51-preparatory changes.

Comment: The Stack Apps entry does not have a description field. Is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: @Felix - StackApps has a description now.  That was just missing, simply.  Woops.